# vb.net linq result in datagridview select with change column order

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

My problem is `dtJoin` result in `datagrid` is not same as in select query column order.

It show `Address` field first then `ClientCd` then `ClientName` then `MemberCd`

I don't know the reason why it show result on order of column name?

My code is

```
Dim dtClient As DataTable
dtClient = getDataTable_sql(SqlStr, SQLCnn)
dtJoin = (From C In dtClient Select C!MemberCd, C!ClientCd, C!Address, C!ClientName).ToList
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtJoin
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: I've never seen this syntax, what does these `!` do?

Comment: 1) If you want to change the column order, change it in the sql statement. 2) Have you set the datagrid to autogenerate the columns or have you added column definitions?

Comment: @TimSchmelter These are dictionary member access expressions, have a look at the [language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712034%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @DominicKexel: Thanks. Never used (or missed) them. However, just out of curiosity, is there an equivalent in C#?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, I don't think so. It's just part of the VB6/VBA-legacy and was often called the *Bang*-operator.

Comment: no i not set autogenerate columns and one thing i tell u when i see dtJoin at runtime in quick watch it show fine in every row but in particular row it show address then clientcd ... same as i told in past

Answer (score 0):

Set `DataSource` of `DataGridView1` to `Nothing` before reloading the datasource.

```
Dim dtClient As DataTable
dtClient = getDataTable_sql(SqlStr, SQLCnn)
dtJoin = (From C In dtClient Select C!MemberCd, C!ClientCd, C!Address, C!ClientName).ToList
'-------------------
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
'-------------------
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtJoin
```

Comment: i try to set datagridview1.datasource = nothing but it's not working